# Local method variable, unrecognized

Tags: java

I have a method `public int bar()`, where i have declared an `int total`(in the method body ofc). So this should be a simpel local variable, the thing is that eclipse complain about

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The local variable total may not have been initialized  Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 35 Java Problem
```

general example :

```
public int foo(){
    int total;
    for(... : ...){
        total += 1; // complains
    }
    return total;// complains
}
```

and my exact code:

```
public int getLocatars(){
    int total;
    for ( Map.Entry<Apartment, List<Expense>> entry : dic.entrySet() ) {
        if(entry.getKey().isDebt()){
            total += entry.getKey().getNrProple();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

I have no idea what I may have done wrong, so any idea is helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable isn't definitely assigned a value, so you can't read it.

Imagine if your entry set is empty, or has no `debt` entries... what value would you want to return?

More than that, even if it *does* get into the inner-most part of your loop, what initial value would you expect to be added to?

Unlike static and instance fields, local variables don't have default values: you have to assign values to them before you read them. I suspect you just want:

```
int total = 0;
```

Comment: yeah, sadly this is non intuitive design. it works on fields but not on local variables.

Comment: thanks. >.> cna't belive it didn't ring a bell, somehow iw as sure java inits ints to 0....

Comment: @FabianLange: I don't think it's unintuitive myself. For local variables, the compiler *knows* the valid execution flows. It can't know whether a setter will be called before a getter for instant/static fields.

Answer (score 4):

Change it from:

```
int total;
```

to:

```
int total = 0;
```

For better understanding, see: [differences between declaration and initialization.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment)