# Static final variable along with static initializer block

Tags: java

I made a class that contains:

1. `static final` variable
2. `static` initializer block with a `System.out.println()` statement

If I call the `static final` variable from another class, the `static` block does not execute.

As far as I know, the `static` initializer block executes when the class is loaded in memory.

In this case, what is happening at the memory level?

Is the class not loading in memory? If not, where do other classes get the address of the `final static` variable?

---

**Case 1:** `static` block does NOT execute

```
class Test2 {
    static final int a = 20;

    static {
        System.out.println("one");
    }
}
```

**Case 2:** `static` block *does* execute

```
class Test2 {
    static final int a;

    static {
        a = 20;
        System.out.println("one");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test2.a);
    }
}
```

- Case 1:

  ```
  20
  ```
- Case 2:

  ```
  one
  20
  ```

So what is happening at both levels?

Comment: post your code!

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Can you please provide a sample code.

Comment: Describing code is almost *always* inferior to just showing it - ideally a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you also post the output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that your field is of either a primitive type or `String`, and is initialized with a compile-time constant expression.

For static final fields initialized with a constant expression (and only such fields) - any code which refers to the field will have the constant value baked into it, rather than going via the static field which would cause class initialization. The "constant expression" part is important though. We can see this with a small test app:

```
class Fields {
    
    public static final String CONSTANT = "Constant";
    public static final String NON_CONSTANT = new String("Non-constant");
    
    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        System.out.println(Fields.CONSTANT);
        System.out.println(Fields.NON_CONSTANT);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Constant
Initializing
Non-constant
```

Accessing the constant field does *not* require initialization, but accessing the non-constant one does. Using a non-final field would have the same effect: it would no longer count as a constant, basically.

The information about "this is a constant" gets baked into the class declaring a field. For example, using `javap -c Fields` we see the two fields:

```
public static final java.lang.String CONSTANT;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
  ConstantValue: String Constant

public static final java.lang.String NON_CONSTANT;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
```

Note the `ConstantValue` part of the `CONSTANT` field metadata, which is missing from the `NON_CONSTANT` field metadata.

See [section 15.28 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for more on what constitutes a constant expression.

[Section 12.4.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) specifies when a class is initialized:

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used **and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4)**.
> - T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Actually I read when first time class name comes inside code. That time class loads in memory. Is this right? if wrong when class loads?

Comment: @deepak: That's wrong, as you've seen - see my edit for details of when a class is initialized.

Comment: Bullet 3 of Section 12.4.1 might lead one to believe that `CONSTANT` is _assigned_ the value "Constant" and thus causes class initialization, but the field is instead _initialized_ and thus Bullet 3 does not apply. [This wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment) can help differentiate between field initialization and assignment.

Comment: By the way, bullet 5 in the same section has gone rogue.

Comment: @Ichiro: Fixed the bullet. I'll leave your comment to speak for itself.

Answer (score 11):

1. A static final field is a compile-time constant and its value is
   hardcoded into the destination class without a reference to its
   origin;
2. therefore your main class does not trigger the loading of the class
   containing the field;
3. therefore the static initializer in that class is not executed.

See the magic removing `final` from definition. You will see static initialiser executing

Comment: This isn't actually the whole story - it doesn't apply to *all* static final fields, as your first point implies. See my answer for more details.