# ARM in JAVA 7(try with resources),error while re-assigning value to any variable of AutoCloseable type

Tags: java-7

I was working on the new try with resources block which automatically invokes close() method of AutoCloseable

I wanted to know that why doesnt the compiler allow me to re-assign a value to the varable after has been declared.

Check this out:-

```
try (FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("c:\\code\\audit.txt");ObjectInputStream is= new ObjectInputStream(fs);fs = new FileInputStream("c:\\code\\log.txt")) {
```

Compilation error:-

```
 VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
    fs cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that **declares** one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

It clearly says, it only declares variables, not assigned.
So this gives compilation error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment) is use-full link which explains that.

Additionally, Then it says,

> Note that the close methods of resources are called in the opposite order of their creation.

So its obvious, so it can't close a resource which already closed.

Answer (score -1):

if Resource reference variable start reassigning then resource which was previously  pointing resource will be opened still and that will be waist , so  only new pointing resource will be  closed , due to this reason compiler  raise Compile time  error.  "auto-closeable resource  xxx  may not be assigned"  . based on java 1.7