# "Error or bug" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

Im trying to create my JFrame like I do always but I don't know why it throws a java.lang.NullpointerException.

I read that it is because you didn;t asign a value, or null can;t be used as a value but I'm almost sure my code is written correctly.

Here it is:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mathme extends JFrame {
    JFrame home;      
    JLabel title; 

    public Mathme(){
        home.setResizable(false);           !!!13!!!!   
        home.setLocationRelativeTo(null);            
        home.setVisible(true);
        home.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        home.setSize(600,500);
        home.setTitle("Pruebax1");
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mathme c = new Mathme(); !!!!23!!!
    }
}
```

And it throws exactly this:

```
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mathme.Mathme.<init>(Mathme.java:13)
    at mathme.Mathme.main(Mathme.java:23)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)***
```

I will put the number of the line which is referred there.

Comment: You never assign a value to `home`...

Comment: Please check out [Java Variable Declaration vs. Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize the home variable to any object so it makes sense that you'll see a NPE if you try to call methods off of it.

i.e.,

```
// this declares a variable but doesn't assign anything to it
JFrame home;  // home is not assigned and is currently null
```

and not

```
// this both declares a variable and assigns an object reference to it.
JFrame home = new JFrame();
```

Also why do you have the class extend JFrame and then try to create another one inside the class?

Regarding "beautiful" code -- you will want to learn Java's code formatting rules. You shouldn't indent code randomly but rather all code in a single block should be indented the same amount.

Regarding:

> I read that it is because you didnt asign a value, or null cant be used as a value but WTF, I mean Im almost sure my code is written correctly.

This means that you don't yet understand what it means to "assign a value" which is different from declaring a variable (see above) and which is well explained in the first pages of most any intro to Java book. Note that Swing GUI programming is a fairly advanced branch of Java programming, and you will likely be better off first going through some basic tutorials of books before jumping into GUI programming.

---

This would be another way to create a GUI similar to what you tried to create:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MathmePanel  extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 500;

   public MathmePanel() {
      // create my GUI here
   }

   // set size in a flexible and safe way
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return superSize;
      }
      int prefW = Math.max(PREF_W, superSize.width);
      int prefH = Math.max(PREF_H, superSize.height);
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MathmePanel mainPanel = new MathmePanel();

      // create JFrame rather than override it
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pruebax1");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Start Swing GUI in a safe way on the Swing event thread
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```