# mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE); mBtAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

Android studio keeps saying `mBluetoothManager` is an unknown class. Can anyone explain?

```
mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBtAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
```

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare the variables before initializing them? [(difference in terms explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment)

You can try adding the types here like this to declare the variables if you did not:

```
BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
```

Also, make sure you have the right classes imported like this at the top of the file:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
```

Android Studio can help you find which classes to import by right clicking on the file in the project view and selecting 'Optimize imports'. There is also a keyboard shortcut for this but it is probably Operating System-specific so I'll let you look it up.