# Issue while initializing a variable

Tags: java, variables

just started programming and my adventure with Java today. I did some exercises from Project Euler, unfortunately at third I hit a wall. Can someone explain me why variable called "czynnikx" isn't initialized, even though I did that in line 4?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your variable, only declared it. You need to actually set it to a value somewhere: `czynnickx = 323432543455465L;`.

You are trying to assign a value to 'czynnik' that has never been initialized.