# Interface declared is NULL

Tags: java, android, interface, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit HTTP middle layer for API calls.Since Retrofit works async, I am using an interface to return API response back.But the declared interface is showing as NULL within the **OnResponse()** overriden method of Retrofit.

Below is the code block(s),

**Interface**

```
public interface OnResponseListener{
        void getCountryListResponse(ArrayList<String> list,int responseCode);
    }
```

**OnResponse**

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Country>> call, Response<List<Country>> response) {

                Log.d("Response",response.body().toString());
                for (Country country: response.body())
                {
                    Log.d("Country",country.toString());
                    Log.d("CommomName",country.getCommonName());
                   // Log.d("BLLL",country.getCommonName());
                   countryList.add(country.getCommonName());
                }
                Log.d("Entered","Vikas Entered");
              //  Log.d("ResonseListener",mResponseListener.toString());//Here throwing error, mResponseListener is null object
                mResponseListener.getCountryListResponse(countryList,response.code());
            }
```

**Interface Declaration**

```
private  OnResponseListener mResponseListener;
```

I have no idea why it is NULL, even after the Object(Interface) is declared. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you put complete method of onResponse here?

Comment: you have to intialize listener

Comment: You have only created its object. You haven't register  your interface.

Comment: Hi @Piyush, how to register interface.?? We cannot initialize interface like classes right..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bunch of suggestions for you.

- Every object is null in Java, if you don't initialise it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614072/6891563).
- Will you make 100 `OnResponseListener` interface for 100 types of response. That's why [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) come to scene.
- Why not you make a common class which will make calls for you, and give expected response?

**I am showing my class which will clear all these points**

The code to call an webservice is just this.

If you have BaseModel type response.

```
Call<BaseModel> call;
new RetroService().call(call, new RetroService.OnResponseListenerRetro<BaseModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String tag, BaseModel response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String tag, RetroService.ErrorType error) {
        Toast.makeText(, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

If you have `Model2` type response.

```
Call<Model2> call;
new RetroService().call(call, new RetroService.OnResponseListenerRetro<Model2>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String tag, Model2 response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String tag, RetroService.ErrorType error) {
        Toast.makeText(, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Now you just need to create this class.

**RetroService.java**

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.arsdigitech.angpau.R;
import com.arsdigitech.angpau.appClasses.App;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class RetroService {
    public static final String TAG = "RetroService***";

    public <T> void call(Call<T> call, OnResponseListenerRetro<T> onResponseListener) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    onResponseListener.onSuccess("", response.body());
                } else {
                    ErrorType errorType = ErrorType.getErrorTypeByVolleyError(response.code());
                    onResponseListener.onError("", errorType);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
                if (t instanceof JsonSyntaxException) {
                    onResponseListener.onError("", ErrorType.ParseError);
                } else {
                    onResponseListener.onError("", ErrorType.Error);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public enum ErrorType {
        Error(R.string.error),
        RequestTimeoutError(R.string.timeoutError),
        NoConnectionError(R.string.noConnectionError),
        AuthFailureError(R.string.authFailureError),
        ServerError(R.string.serverError),
        NetworkError(R.string.networkError),
        BadRequestError(R.string.badRequestError),
        ForbiddenError(R.string.forbiddenError),
        NotFoundError(R.string.notFoundError),
        UnsupportedMediaType(R.string.unsupportedMediaType),
        MethodNotAllowedError(R.string.methodNotAllowedError),
        ParseError(R.string.parsing_error),;
        int message;

        ErrorType(int message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return App.getAppRes().getString(message);
        }

        public static @Nullable
        ErrorType getErrorTypeByVolleyError(int errorCode) {
            ErrorType errorType = null;
            switch (errorCode) {
                case 400:
                    errorType = ErrorType.BadRequestError;
                    break;
                case 401:
                    errorType = ErrorType.AuthFailureError;
                    break;
                case 403:
                    errorType = ErrorType.ForbiddenError;
                    break;
                case 404:
                    errorType = ErrorType.NotFoundError;
                    break;
                case 408:
                    errorType = ErrorType.RequestTimeoutError;
                    break;
                case 500:
                case 501:
                case 502:
                case 503:
                case 504:
                case 505:
                    errorType = ErrorType.ServerError;
                    break;
                default:
                    errorType = ErrorType.Error;
            }
            return errorType;
        }
    }

    public interface OnResponseListenerRetro<T> {
        void onSuccess(String tag, T response);
        void onError(String tag, ErrorType error);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Khemraj. i understood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set value in it, and implement it from where you are calling it :

create a method :

```
public void setResponseListener(OnResponseListener mResponseListener){
    this.mResponseListener = mResponseListener;
}
```

and call it from where you are calling this call.enqueue() method like following registration
:

```
    RestClientClassObject.setResponseListener(new OnResponseListener() {
        @Override
        void getCountryListResponse(ArrayList<String> list, int responseCode) {

            //write code you want to do with list

        }

    });
```

Comment: Hi @NehaK, what is RestClientClassObject .?? I'm using Retrofit for HTTP request and response.

Comment: please post you class in which you have written onResponse() , and from where you are calling it, I will tell you how to do it