# What is the difference between- Employee e = new Employee(); and Employee e;

Tags: java, class, object, reference, instance

What is the difference between-

`Employee e = new Employee();`
and
`Employee e;`

If Employee is a class. Where would we use it in programs to satisfy our code?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try basic Java tutorial?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not really. Local variables are not initialized to null, and you can declare them and initialize them later.

Comment: `Employee e` declares a variable `e`, of type `Employee`. If it's a field, the variable is initialized to null. If it's a local variable, it's not initialized. `Employee e = new Employee()` declares a variable `e`of type Employee, and initializes it with an newly created Employee object. Every Java book or tutorial explains that. Do some basic research please. You can't learn programming on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is an **initialization**. You create a new object and assign it to the variable `e` :

```
Employee e = new Employee();
```

The second example is a **declaration**. You just associate a variable name with an object type:

```
Employee e;
```

As it was mentioned by @JBNizet whether the `e` is initialized or not depends on where you declare this variable.

If it is class member then it gets `null` as a default value. If it is a local variable then it doesn't get any default value(undefined).

See more [Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

And [Java: define terms initialization, declaration and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614072/java-define-terms-initialization-declaration-and-assignment)

Comment: The first one makes an `Employee` object AND initializes it as a new `Employee` object. The second one makes an `Employee` object, but doesn't initialize it. Thus, the second example defines it as null.

Comment: @FailingCoder "_makes an `Employee` object_" is misleading—"make" seems similar to "instantiate". The second example merely declares a variable of type `Employee`, which will be initialized to `null` if it's a field, but does not "make" an `Employee` object.

Comment: Maybe my `word choice` is incorrect. I'm pretty sure I got the right idea though?

Comment: The first example is a declaration plus an initialization.