# difference between X x = new X(); and x = new X();

Tags: java, class

Say I have created classes and now in main method, I want to assign and call them.

I write: `X x = new X();` and `x = new X();`

What is/are the difference/differences between these two?

Comment: Second won't work unless you have declared the `x` variable previously.

Comment: ohh, okay that's clear now

Comment: Possibly related: [Java: define terms initialization, declaration and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614072)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `X` is a class with a no-arg constructor (for example a default constructor), the following works:

```
    // Declare and initialize x
    X x = new X();
    // Assign new value to x
    x = new X();
```

The first code line declares a variable `x` and assigns a reference to the new instance of `X` to it (a new `X` object). The second line assigns a new `X` instance to the already declared variable `x` (thus discarding the reference to the first object). We declare a variable by putting the type name (or the word `var`) before them. So since in the first line, we have `X x`, this is a declaration.

In Java, variables need to be declared before they are first used. So the first code line would not work without the type name `X` at the front. Java would complain that the variable `x` had not been declared.

On the other hand, we are only allowed to declare each variable once. So putting type name `X` before the second line would be an error too. My Eclipse says *Duplicate local variable x* because it “thinks” that I am trying to declare a second variable also named `x`, which is not allowed (for good reasons).

Comment: when we say "new instance of", what do we mean by that?

Comment: An instance of `X` is an object created from the class `X`. @jjavid